# Get last time timedatectl synchronized its time/force synchronization now

Tags: ubuntu, date

I have an Ubuntu server that is a little over a minute out of sync with the actual time. When I run timedatectl I get:

```
Local time: Tue 2018-04-24 14:47:57 MDT
Universal time: Tue 2018-04-24 20:47:57 UTC
RTC time: Tue 2018-04-24 20:47:57
Timezone: America/Denver (MDT, -0600)
NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
RTC in local TZ: no
DST active: yes
Last DST change: DST began at
          Sun 2018-03-11 01:59:59 MST
          Sun 2018-03-11 03:00:00 MDT
Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
          Sun 2018-11-04 01:59:59 MDT
          Sun 2018-11-04 01:00:00 MST
```

My understanding is that it should be synchronizing using NTP. It's possible ntp isn't working quite right. If I run ntpq -p I get:

```
remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
======================================================================
propjet.latt.ne .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
time-a-g.nist.g .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
linode227395.st .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
dev.smatwebdesi .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
pugot.canonical .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Is there a way to tell when the last time was that it synced and from what server. Also, how do I force synchronization right now to fix the problem (I know I can manually set the date, but I won't get it quite right, and I want to actually fix the syncing).

Comment: For me, the reason ntp was not working is the firewall was blocking outgoing traffic on high numbered ports that were required by NTP.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Checking status

Since Ubuntu 16.04 timesyncd which is part of systemd is now responsible (out of the box) for syncing date/time. You can check its status using `systemctl`:

```
$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
           └─disable-with-time-daemon.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-08-05 10:14:44 EDT; 11min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 3714 (systemd-timesyn)
   Status: "Synchronized to time server 108.59.2.24:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org)."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           └─3714 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

Aug 05 10:14:44 pi-hole systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Aug 05 10:14:44 pi-hole systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Aug 05 10:14:45 pi-hole systemd-timesyncd[3714]: Synchronized to time server 108.59.2.24:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org).
```

Or through `journalctl`:

```
$ journalctl -u systemd-timesyncd
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 13:16:42 EDT, end at Sun 2018-08-05 10:20:01 EDT. --
Aug 05 10:14:44 pi-hole systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Aug 05 10:14:44 pi-hole systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Aug 05 10:14:45 pi-hole systemd-timesyncd[3714]: Synchronized to time server 108.59.2.24:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org).
```

You can also watch `systemd/clock`:

```
$ stat /var/lib/systemd/clock
  File: /var/lib/systemd/clock
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: b302h/45826d    Inode: 18750       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  100/systemd-timesync)   Gid: (  103/systemd-timesync)
Access: 2018-08-05 10:22:13.838262405 -0400
Modify: 2018-08-05 10:22:13.838262405 -0400
Change: 2018-08-05 10:22:13.838262405 -0400
 Birth: -
```

The Access/Modify/Change times on this file show when systemd-timesynd last touched it.

#### Forcing a sync

It doesn't appear that there's any method to force a sync directly. Restarting the `systemd-timesyncd` service does in fact trigger a resync though:

```
$ systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd
```

You can see this in the logs:

```
$ journalctl -u systemd-timesyncd
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 13:16:42 EDT, end at Sun 2018-08-05 10:44:37 EDT. --
Aug 05 10:14:44 pi-hole systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Aug 05 10:14:44 pi-hole systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Aug 05 10:14:45 pi-hole systemd-timesyncd[3714]: Synchronized to time server 108.59.2.24:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Aug 05 10:44:37 pi-hole systemd[1]: Stopping Network Time Synchronization...
Aug 05 10:44:37 pi-hole systemd[1]: Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
Aug 05 10:44:37 pi-hole systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Aug 05 10:44:37 pi-hole systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Aug 05 10:44:37 pi-hole systemd-timesyncd[4157]: Synchronized to time server 208.75.88.4:123 (0.debian.pool.ntp.org).
```

The last line is from my restart.

#### Controlling interval

You can control the interval which this polls the NTP servers through these properties in the `systemd-timesyncd` config file `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`:

> ```
>    PollIntervalMinSec=, PollIntervalMaxSec=
>
>    The minimum and maximum poll intervals for NTP messages. Each setting takes a time 
>    value (in seconds). PollIntervalMinSec= must not be smaller than 16 seconds. 
>    PollIntervalMaxSec= must be larger than PollIntervalMinSec=. PollIntervalMinSec= 
>    defaults to 32 seconds, and PollIntervalMaxSec= defaults to 2048 seconds.
> ```

The above appears to have been added in late 2017 - [timesync: make poll interval configurable #7268](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/7268).

#### References

- [ntpd vs. systemd-timesyncd - How to achieve reliable NTP syncing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305643/ntpd-vs-systemd-timesyncd-how-to-achieve-reliable-ntp-syncing)
- [How to force a clock update using ntp?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254826/how-to-force-a-clock-update-using-ntp)
- [How to force NTPD to update date/time after boot?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/how-to-force-ntpd-to-update-date-time-after-boot/87762#87762)
- [systemd/man/timesyncd.conf.html](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timesyncd.conf.html)

Comment: Another option would probably be to check the modify date on /run/systemd/timesyncd/syncronized. It gets removed on reboot tho, which might be a positive as well tho

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of good info in @slm's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460660/212513), but it appears to be Debian-specific, and the OP wanted to know when the time was last synchronised on Ubuntu. The best option on 22.04 appears to be to either `ls` or `stat` either of these two files:

```
/var/lib/systemd/timesync/clock
/run/systemd/timesync/synchronized
```

This will give the last sync time, but this will probably only change every 30 or 40 minutes.

If you simply run `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service` my systems give a status of 'Initial synchronisation to time server', rather than 'Synchronized to time server', which isn't helpful, and leaves you wondering whether the system synchronised only once.

`journalctl -u systemd-timesyncd` shows only what happened during the last boot, and it may not show even that.

Note that the OP's comment that

> For me, the reason ntp was not working is the firewall was blocking
> outgoing traffic on high numbered ports that were required by NTP

Doesn't really make sense. On modern systems, `timedatectl` doesn't require *any* ports to be explicitly opened, because the firewall is NTP-aware and can track UDP responses to port 123. On one system I've just checked, the firewall is blocking incoming packets on UDP 123 (from arbitrary IP addresses), but NTP is still updating.